# Excel Pandas Python question on IndexingError, can search and remove columns fine containing certain words, but not rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this code

```
    searchfor = ["s", 'John']
df = df[~df.iloc[1].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(searchfor),na=False)]
```

This returns the error

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

However this works fine if run as a column search

```
df = df[~df.iloc[;,1].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(searchfor),na=False)]
```

I am trying to remove a row based on if the row contains a certain phrase

Comment: Can you clarify better what you intend to do? Do you want to delete the row if any column of that row contains an element of your list "searchfor"?

Comment: Yes that is correct, if the row contains a certain term, I want to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To drop rows**

Create a mask which returns True or False depending whether that cell contains your strings

```
search_for = ["s", "John"]
mask = data.applymap(lambda x: any(s in str(x) for s in search_for))
```

Then use filter .any to check for at least one True per row with boolean indexing and take only the rows where no True was found.

```
df_filtered = df[~mask.any(axis=1)]
```

**To drop columns**

```
search_for = ["s", "John"]
mask = data.applymap(lambda x: any(s in str(x) for s in search_for))
```

axis=0 instead of 1 to check for each column:

```
columns_analysis = mask.any(axis=0)
```

get the indexes when True to drop

```
columns_to_drop = columns_analysis[columns_analysis == True].index.tolist()
df_filtered = data.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I use this method of doing things to remove a column containing it (I have the method I already used to do this, but in terms of tidyness)

Comment: Are you using axis=1 in .any()? It should only take out the rows.

Comment: Sorry I worked out what i was doing wrong and quickly edited my comment to ask something else

Comment: As an additional question how would I change this to search in the list searchfor here, and not just individual strings written out each time

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the way you are splitting your data. 
In the first statement, you are asking python to split your dataframe and give you the second (index 1 is second if you want first change index to 0) row, while in the second case, you are asking for the second column and in your dataframe these have different lengths (my mistake, is shapes). See this example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3':[23,23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

col1    col2    col3
    1   3   23
    2   4   23
```

First row:

```
df.iloc[0]
col1     1
col2     3
col3    23
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

First column:

```
df.iloc[:,]
    1
    2
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Try this and if you like the answer vote...
Good luck.

Comment: I think I understand this however I don't see why having them being different lengths is actually a problem, why does that prevent me selecting the row to remove

Comment: Can you add an example of your df we an play with. That may help us understand better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it is a simple test sheet with test1-test4 as columns, and 5 rows filled with 1 or S.

Comment: then you can try: df[df[test-1].isin(['s','john'])==False] that should give you all the row that do not have s or john in the cells in column test-1. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Er no, I am looking for a way to search by row, so looking for a "s" in row 2 for example and removing that row if it contains s

Comment: df[df[test-1].isin(['s','john'])==False] this will do that if the cell is exact match. You are saying you will need to remove cells like 's', or 's1', both contain s. Add an example of the dataframe